# Where and how is a tinker-graph stored

Tags: tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I have just started with gremlin. I have successfully built and stored a graph on gremlin-server using python script, using the package gremlin_python.

I was curious to know how is the data of the graph stored on disk, but could not find it. (I did find that Titan graphDB stores it in Cassandra/HBase but I'm not using Titan, just the gremlin-server.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TinkerGraph is an in-memory graph database, so it does not store anything to the file system and is non-transactional in nature. You can however configure it to write its contents on close to a specified format by setting these configuration properties:

- `gremlin.tinkergraph.graphLocation`
- `gremlin.tinkergraph.graphFormat`

Those settings and how to use them are described in the TinkerPop [reference documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_configuration_3).